# php allow only @, _, -, and . from input

Tags: php

So I want to get email address from HTML form. And when i get email in PHP how to check if is in string only allowed special chars(`@, _, -, and .`)? For example: email input is `!#asd@example.com`

```
$input = !#asd@example.com;
if( check is only allowed chars in $input string ){
   //there is only allowed and check is ok
} else {
   //there is not only allowed check and do something else
}
```

Comment: Why not FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL instead?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you only need to validate email, you have many options to validate it:

a. Use HTML5 input field for email

```
<input type="email" name="email" />
```

b. Filter_validate_email

Comment: Where option a is a userfriendly but unsecure validation because this validation is browserside and easy to bypass. Because of that reason you should ALWAYS validate serverside as well.

Comment: Using the HTML5 'email' is not an (single) option for validating emails. The data should ALWAYS be validated server-side. `Filter_validate_email` is the most correct function for doing this.

Comment: I always use option a and i was searched for option b and i now use both to be 100% sure thanks.

Comment: Using both is perfect. It will give the end-user a nicer experience when the browser is capable of handling HTML5 / email fields, plus you will ALWAYS be able to validate the email address on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE)
{
    $errors['email'] = 'This is not a valid email';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fist you find the existence of special characters in the string then implement the check to allow only specific characters

```
    if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $input))
    {

       if (strpos($input,'@') === true || strpos($input,'-') === true strpos($input,'_') === true strpos($input,'.') === true) {

        // do something

    }
  }
```